# Как извлечь первый индекс массива?

Tags: массивы, php

День добрый!

Есть массив:

[0] => "1",
[1] => "1",
[2] => "1",
[3] => "1",

С помощью unset($array[$key]) удалил идексы: 0 и 1

Задача:

a) Извлечь первый индекс из оставленного массива

б) Пронумеровать массив заново с 0'го индекса

Кто поможет решить данную проблему?( вариант любой на выбор "а" или "б"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Thx =) Вроде то что нужно